# A player-falling system (basically gravity)

Tags: java, gravity

I am making a game that is similar to Doodle Jump, getting your player as high as possible. Now, I got my player working, and moving. But, the problem is, I don't have gravity, or anything that will make the player fall down onto the ground again. Do you guys have any idea of doing this? I tried having the player get a constant force, being pushed down at all times, but, it's not smooth, and it doesn't act like real falling. Can I have some help with making this player-falling system?

Edit:

```
    GRAVITY = 10;
    TERMINAL_VELOCITY = 300;
    vertical_speed = 0;

    public void fall(){ 
    this.vertical_speed = this.vertical_speed + GRAVITY;
    if(this.vertical_speed > TERMINAL_VELOCITY){
        this.vertical_speed = TERMINAL_VELOCITY;
    }
    this.y = this.y - this.vertical_speed;
}
```

I made this, didn't work, shoots my player up in the air.

Comment: There's a constant *acceleration* that we are accelerated at. It's NOT a constant velocity. That's why your falling didn't look right.

Comment: "didn't work, shoots my player up in the air."  Consider that you have the sign of the speed wrong.  Maybe you should subtract GRAVITY instead of add?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the real world gravity will increase the rate of a fall by a constant amount over time (9.8 meters per second **per second**). You could simulate this by giving the player a vertical speed (when they jump or fall off a platform) and then subtracting a constant amount from that value every time round the main game loop so that they accelerate over time.  You'll want to put a maximum limit on this (terminal velocity) otherwise when they fall a long way they could hit ludicrous speed fairly quickly.  The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
const GRAVITY = 10;
const TERMINAL_VELOCITY = 300;

object Player 
{
    int vertical_speed = 0;
    int vertical_position;  

    function fall ()
    {
        this.vertical_speed = this.vertical_speed + GRAVITY;
        if (this.vertical_speed > TERMINAL_VELOCITY)
        {
            this.vertical_speed = TERMINAL_VELOCITY;
        }
        this.vertical_position = this.vertical_position - this.vertical_speed;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: **9.8 Metres Per Second Per Second is correct!  Please don't edit it!**  Acceleration is measured as change in velocity over time, expressed in metres per second per second.  9.8 meters per second per second means that after 1 second a stationary object would have accelerated enough to be travelling at 9.8 m/s.  After 2 seconds, it will have attained a speed of 19.6 m/s.  After 3 seconds it will have attained a speed of 29.4 m/s and so on.

I honestly don't believe I even had to explain that.

Comment: Right, I wrote your psuedocode in Java, I edited it into the OP, now, I put this in my update() method, which updates every frame. Now what happens is, when I start it, it will suddenly shoot upwards, and not come back. Can you see what I did wrong? The this.y is the y position of the player.

Comment: @Stan. You need to add rather than subtract. Down is teh positive direction on the y axis. i.e. this.y = this.y + this.vertical_speed;

Comment: Are you assuming that the this is called once per second and that vertical speed is in m/s, otherwise you can't just add gravity to vertical speed to get the new speed

Comment: If the acceleration's too fast, then you can a) use a smaller gravity constant and/or b) don't recompute the fall velocity every time through the loop.  If you do it on every third iteration then the acceleration will be three times less.  If the character is falling up instead of down, then add the velocity instead of subtract it.

Comment: I wouldn't use terminal velocity in this way. I would think of an air resistance (of some imaginary air), which is proportional to the square of square (i.e. ``coeffitient * speed ^2``), and substract that from the gravitational acceleration. This way, as the velocity grows, the acceleration decreases up to the point that it is zero, i.e. the object has reached the terminal velocity. The resistance coefficient can be computed beforehand to get arbitrary terminal velocity. It might look more real.

Comment: @JanŽegklitz That might be slightly overkill, I don't believe most platform games from the golden age of consoles went to such lengths, for example (in fact I doubt most games prior to the rise of the physics engine did), all you really need is a limit to stop things accelerating forever.

Answer (score 5):

Do you know the formula for gravity?

```
velocity = acceleration * time
```

`acceleration` is the gravitational acceleration.

`time` is the amount of time that has passed.

Also,

```
distance = 1/2 * acceleration * time**2
```

Comment: I see, but, I have no idea how to still actually implent this, do you suggest to make a timer which starts when you at 0 velocity, or something?

Answer (score 2):

A formula to compute the height of an entity with gravity at any given time is like so:

```
       g * t ^ 2
s(t) = --------- + v * t + h
           2
```

Where `s` is the function of time (`time` to `height`), `g` is the gravity factor (9.8 for metres), `v` is the original upwards velocity, and `h` is the original height.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a constant force acting on the person, you need to have the person accelerate while they fall.

They should start falling with `0` velocity.  Then, you should increase the force as they fall.

To do this, you will need to update their velocity over time:

Something like this:

```
if (stillFalling) {
    velocity = velocity + (gravity_constant) * time_interval;
} else {
    velocity = 0;
}
```

You will want to continuously update the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You will find explanations and a demo on [that website](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Physics/Chapter02/index.html). I suggest too that you read a book on physics or at least some wiki article about gravity.

Answer (score 0):

From my Experience, do something like this.

```
public void run() {
    if(velY+g>TerminalVel) {
        velY=TerminalVel;
    } else {
        velY+=g; 
    }
    y+=velY;
}
```

The method run() should be in a loop.