# Create Java 2D gravity?

Tags: java, 2d, platform, gravity

I'm creating java game (I'm a beginner with this for now) and I'd like to start with some kind of platform game.

I'd like to know how I can make the player jump (I know how to move him up and down), but I don't know how how to make him go back down after going up.

Here is my code:

```
    public void keyPress() {
        if (listener.arrowUp) {
        Jump();
    }
}

private void Jump() {
    if(player.get(1).getPosY() > maxJump) {
        player.get(1).moveY(-10);
    } else if(player.get(1).getPosY() == maxJump) {
        player.get(1).moveY(85);
    }
}
```

So.. the player moves -10px upwards as long as i press 'w' and when he hits maxJump (which is 375 and players position at the start is 465) he "teleports" back to 465 instead of sliding back down like he does when going up.. It's really hard to explain this without a video, but i hope somebody understands and can help me with this.

Comment: It is common (and efficient) to create general objects and entities, give them some features (can jump? shoots?) and then subclass the player character, the enemies, the bosses out of those general classes... If you design your game like this, then it is much easier to wrap some entities in another class that called (let's say) environment and add a feature to the environment (like gravity).

Comment: The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21785654 includes a complete example that you can simply compile and run. It refers to a projectile being shot, but the motion of the object (and the basic technique for computing the movement) are the same as for a jump.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111574/a-player-falling-system-basically-gravity?rq=1) question gives a basic answer to yours. Now in your jump function, you have to set the `vertical_speed` only once and only call `fall()` every frame and add some `moveY`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternatives:

Option 1. Simulating some very simple physics. You add forces to your player, so pressing the up arrow will add a force that makes the player move upwards. Gravity is constantly applied and thus it will gradually cancel out the force you applied when the up arrow was pressed. Perhaps you only want to use forces in the vertical direction you do something like this:

```
// Each frame
if(notOnTheGround){
    verticalVelocity -= GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT;
}

// When user jumps
vertivalVelocity += JUMP_FORCE;
```

Option 2.  An alternative is to kind of animate the jumps using [projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

```
// Each frame
if(isJumping){
    verticalVelocity = initialVelocity*sin(angle) - g*animationTime;
    animationTime += TIME_STEP;
}

// When user jumps
isJumping = true;
animationTime = 0;
initialVelocity = ... // calculate initial velocity
```