# Gravity system in a simple java game

Tags: java, gravity

A friend and I are starting to make a simple Java game and my job was to make a JFrame that has a player block that can jump on a platform. I am able to make the player class by making it extend `Block`.

I have reached a point where I can draw the player, but it only moves up and won't come back down, and the block thats supposed to be the floor wont show up. Here is my Main method, `Block` and `Player` classes, respectively.

```
package michael.s.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class MichaelSGame {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lab 54");
static JPanel panel;
static int height = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
static int width = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
static Player player = new Player(5,5,height - 20,width/2,0,0,Color.BLUE);
static Block floor = new Block(10,width,width,height - 20,Color.GREEN){
    @Override
    public void update() {
        if(isTouching(player))
                player.vy=0;
    }
};
public static void main(String[] args) {   


    panel = new JPanel(){
        //@Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            floor.paint(g);
            player.paint(g);


        }
    };        
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    KeyListener controls = new KeyListener(){
      @Override
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

      }

      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
         {
             player.jump();
         }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            player.left();
         }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
         {
            player.right();
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
      {
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
         {
             player.stop();
         }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
         {
             player.stop();
         }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
         {
             player.stop();   
         }


      }
  };
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setFocusable(true);
    panel.addKeyListener(controls);
    panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    });        
    frame.setVisible(true);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
              while(true){
                  floor.update();
                  player.update();
                  panel.repaint();
                  Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);
              }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }).start();
}
}
```

///////////////////////////////

```
package michael.s.game;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public abstract class Block {
    protected int ht;
    protected int wt;
    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    protected Color color;
    public Block(int ht, int wt, double x, double y, Color color)
    {
        this.ht = ht;
        this.wt = wt;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }
    public boolean isTouching(Block other)
    {
       return x+wt >= other.getX() && other.getX() + other.getWt() >= x && y+ht >= other.getY() && other.getY() + other.getHt() >= y; 
    }
    public int getX()
    {
        return (int) x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return (int) y;
    }
    public int getHt()
    {
        return this.ht;
    }
    public int getWt()
    {
        return this.wt;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), wt, ht);
    }

    public abstract void update();
}
```

/////////////////

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package michael.s.game;

import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class Player extends Block 
{
    public double vx;
    public double vy;
    public double GRAVITY;
    public Player(int ht, int wt, double x, double y, double vx, double vy, Color color)
    {
        super(ht,wt,x,y, color);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() 
    {
        vy+= GRAVITY;
        x+=vx;
        y+=vy;
    }
    public void left()
    {
        vx = -5;
    }
    public void right()
    {
        vx = 5;
    }
    public void jump()
    {
        vy = -10;
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        vy = 0;
    }


}
```

How can I get gravity to work in this, and have the floor actually show up?

I need help on adding a gravity function, having the floor show itself, and having the player stop when the player hits the floor.

Comment: [How do i ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please boil down the problem.

Comment: I think all you need is there : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6111628/2696865

Comment: my problem is that i cant add player gravity and have the floor show up

Comment: Are you saying that when your player jumps, they keep going up, and don't get pulled down?

Comment: No. They move up and stop....but won't get pulled down